# How to give scroll bar,height to autocomplete showing list?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, vb.net

I have used auto complete function on text box,but for more data it is taking full page,i want to give scroll bar and height to it.

Here is my code:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

     $("#<%LkTxt.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/ETAWebService.asmx/GetLookUp") %>',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                scroll: true,
                scrollHeight: 180,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#<%=CmbHdn.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, just override the CSS!

```
ul.ui-autocomplete { max-height: 350px !important; overflow: auto !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Textbox in which you are applying autocomplete put it in a div define a class for that div and just apply css on that.

Example -

```
  <style>
.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;

    padding-right: 20px;
}
 html .ui-autocomplete {
    height: 100px;
}
</style>

<div class="ui-autocomplete">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />
</div>
```